# How to handle com.netflix.client.ClientException in Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-feign

I have two services: A and B. B makes a request via feign client when starts.
But when A is unavailable I get **com.netflix.client.ClientException**

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: A
```

I'm looking for the best practice for handling such an exception

Comment: That's a very broad question and like depends on the exact context of the application

Comment: I just want to avoid using try-catch block

Comment: I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Not only about this exception in particular, but about any HTTP communication in general, you could use circuit breakers and provide fallback methods that would then handle your logic in an alternative way that would not be calling the service A.

Comment: I tried to handle in controlleradvice. Tried with ClientException & FeignException. But, it is going to Exception.class only. e.getClass there gives RunTimeException

Answer (score 1):

right now there is no official way to catch FeignClient exception. but you can handle FeignClient exception by catching as a java.lang.Exception and throw your own exception.

for ex:

```
try{
   feignClient.feignMethod();
} catch(Exception ex){
  //throw your own exception
  throw new CustomFeignException();
}
```